# Layer trees, No appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement an RB-Tree, in my tree each node has also a pointer to an other RB-Tree. My code looks like this:

```
class node{
    tree* subTree;
    . . . //some code goes here      
   node(){
      subTree = new tree; //error here !!
   }
};


class tree{
  . . . //some code
};
```

the problem is that since `node` is defined before `tree`, The compiler gives me `No appropriate default constructor available`. And If I move the node class after the tree class then again the same problem would happen with the constructor of `node`. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declare class `tree`, then use only a constructor declaration in class `node`,

```
class tree; // forward declaration, allows node to contain incomplete tree types

class node
{
    tree* subTree;
public:
    //some code goes here      
    node(); // only the declaration
};
```

and finally define the `node`'s constructor outside the class, but **after** the full definition of class `tree`,

```
class tree 
{ 
    // implementation 
};

node::node()
{
    subTree = new tree; // no more error here !!
}
```

<kbd>[Live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea68a668ff191705)</kbd>
The trick here is that a class can contain incomplete types (i.e. types for which only a declaration is available, but not the full definition), whenever you use them as pointers/references and do not need to compute/use their size. So, you can forward declare `tree` before class `node`, then declare the pointer `tree* subtree` in your class `node` and only *declare* the constructor. You then *define* the constructor *after* class `tree` is fully defined, since in the constructor you need the size of `tree` because of the `subTree = new tree;` statement. But you are now ok, since the class `tree` is fully available, and the constructor can be defined without problems. Hope this makes sense.

Related: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: @MoNo do a `make clean` before, clear all your previously build object files. If you use an IDE, there should be some option to clean the build. Also make sure your `node` class doesn't use incomplete types whenever it needs full definitions. If there are `node` member functions that need the full definition of `tree`, then define them outside the class `node`, after the definition of the class `tree`.